# rotation of objects in OpenGL using 3D vector and angle

Tags: opengl

I have a problem with the orientation of objects in the OpenGL program, I can't calculate rotation of x, y, z based on 3D vector and angle or 4D vector.
Im working with c++.

I have:

```
Vector3f myVector;
float angle;    
float rotx;
float roty;    
float rotz;

//i need smomething like

doSomething(a,angle,&rotx,&roty,&rotz);    
glRotatef(rotx,1.0,0,0);    
glRotatef(roty,0,1.0,0);    
glRotatef(rotz,0,0,1.0);

// draw object
```

"myVector" is a vector in 3d space. I want to rotate object in direction of vector. "angle" is rotation of object around the vector. "rotx,roty,rotz" are local variables. How to calculate rotx,roty,royz to do this?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Euler_AxisAngle.png

In picture on link my object is oriented in direction of 'x', i want to orinet it in direction of 'e' and 'O' is my "angle".

Comment: I think you forgot the question ;-) .. and can you please provide a bit more details on what you want to achieve?

Comment: It *sounds* like you want a [quaternion representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation) of a rotation - but you don't really specify how your vector / angle are determined, or how they are to be used.

Comment: You can pass the axis and angle directly to glRotatef: `glrotatef(angle,a.x,a.y,a.z)`.  Do you really need to break it into three rotations?

Answer (score 0):

> How to calculate rotx,roty,royz to do this?

There's no unique solution to your problem. For each target direction there are 6 different ways to express it in Euler angles.

The only way to represent rotations unambigously are rotation matrices, or their close relatives, Quaternions.

The parameters to glRotate are very close to a quaternion. In fact the axis parameters are the normalized i,j,k elements of a quaternion and the real quaternion part is the rotation angle in radians.

Comment: This I understood and implemented.
Is there a way to get it back into the domain of vectors where I can multiply it with velocity and the time to get a new position?
Im sory if this is a stupid question.

Comment: @slobacartoonac: Actually quaternions are much better for integrating rotations over time than Euler angles. In fact one of their primary uses in computer graphics is interpolation between rotations. If you really want to stick with Euler angles (*\*shudder*\*) then I'd suggest using a least square optimization to find the set of angles that, when applied to a composition of rotation matrices, minimizes the differece to the matrix represented by the quaternion.

Comment: So tell me if i'm right. I can have object, 3 otogonal vetors (1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1), in my case first represent forward. I transform them with quaternion(rotade them), and then use them for positioning?

Comment: @slobacartoonac: Those three axes you have there, they are in fact a identity transform matrix. When you apply a quaternion to each of them it's just like as if you'd do *one single* call of glRotatef with the right axis and angle, which then transforms the whole matrix. See http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~gewang/projects/darth/stuff/quat_power.html and especially the section "Quaternion to Axis Angle"; you then just use the obtained axis and angle into *one single* glRotate call. *Stop thinking about an orientation being the result of 3 compound rotations*, you need only one!